# Script to edit many text files

Tags: python, bash, scripting

I have a c++ program which generates many data files each of them containing three columns. Now in each of these data files there can be some anomalous entries where the third column would have `-nan`. How do I write a script to so that it opens each of these data files and finds all the rows in which the third column has `nan` and deletes all such rows?
Is it possible to write a script in bash or python that can do this?
Example:

```
100   0.1    15.8334
100   0.2    16.7895
100   0.3     -nan
100   0.4    15.8543
100   0.5      -nan
```

In this file I would like the 3rd and the 5th rows to be deleted so that my file looks like

```
100   0.1    15.8334
100   0.2    16.7895
100   0.4    15.8543
```

Comment: Could you provide a couple of lines of sample data?

Comment: 100   0.1    15.8334
    100   0.2    16.7895
    100   0.3     -nan
100   0.4    15.8543
100   0.5      -nan
In this file I would like the 3rd and the 5th rows to be deleted so that my file looks like
    100   0.1    15.8334
    100   0.2    16.7895
    100   0.4    15.8543

Comment: @SthitadhiRoy In the post. Make sure you indent with four spaces. The actual whitespace (tab/spaces) matters

Comment: Would `sed -i "/nan$/ d" datafile` work?

Comment: `awk '{ if ($3!="-nan") print }'`

Comment: @sehe  `awk '$3 != "-nan"'` is all that's needed :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sed -i -e '/-nan/d' datafile.txt
```

To operate on multiple files, you can replace "datafile.txt" with a glob that matches all the files, or use a for loop

```
for file in data1.txt data2.txt data3.txt; do
    sed -i -e '/-nan/d' $file
done
```

or perhaps the `find` command:

```
find . -name "data*.txt" -exec sed -i -e '/-nan/d' {} +
```

Comment: This creates new files with `e` added to their filenames. But I wanted to keep the filenames the same, I can of course delete the old files and rename the new ones, but it might take a lot of time because the number of files is of the order of thousand.

Comment: My apologies; I didn't check how -i and -e would interact. I was using "sed '/-nan/d' file" but -e apparently is required if you try to specify multiple file to edit.

Answer (score 3):

Something like (in bash):

```
for file in files ;do
  grep -v -- -nan file > file.$$ && mv file.$$ file
done
```

Should probably clean it up in the code though.

Answer (score 1):

This is the basic mechanism:

```
with open('yourfile.txt') as fin, open('yourfile_output.txt', 'w') as fout:
    for line in fin:
        try:
            c1, c2, c3 = line.split()
            if c3 != '-nan':
                fout.write(line)
        except ValueError as e:
            pass # Handle cases where number of cols != 3
```

And then put that in a function and use glob.iglob to reutrn a list of matching filenames and loop...

Another possible option just for completeness:

```
from math import isnan

with open('yourfile.txt') as fin, open('yourfile_output.txt', 'w') as fout:
    for line in fin:
        try:
            c1, c2, c3 = map(float, line.split())
            if not isnan(c3):
                fout.write(line)
        except ValueError as e:
            pass # Handle cases where number of cols != 3
```

Comment: That should be `with open('yourfile.txt') as fin, open('yourfile_output.txt', 'w') as fout:`.

Comment: @Levon Okay - adjusted to have to be exactly equal to 3 which meets the OP statement of 3 columns

Comment: @MRAB thanks - not sure how that extra `with` got there and good catch on 'w' - brain's obviously not kicked into gear properly today

Comment: Uhm yes. Why so complicated? A simple sed line will do.

Comment: @JoSo It ensures there are exactly 3 columns, which are all convertible to float, and handles - '-nan', 'nan', '+nan'. So it's going to be slightly more 'complicated' than a "does this substring exist" command.

Comment: Yes, I already saw that it's 'complicated'. That's why I asked "Why so complicated?".

Comment: @JoSo I just prefer to be slightly cautious about data - when you process 100's of millions of records a month - it's wise to be somewhat doubtful about immediate requirements and quick solutions until you can prove a quick solution is viable